# Can't solve this python problem I got error every time

Tags: python

The Bears in Berlin spend most of the day playing. In particular, they play if
the temperature is between 60 and 90 (inclusive). Unless it is summer, then
the upper limit is 100 instead of 90. Given an int temperature and a boolean
is_summer, return True if the Bears play and False otherwise.
bear_play(70, False) → True
bear_play(95, False) → False
bear_play(95, True) → True

Comment: So what is your question? This isn't a place to give you answers to these sorts of practice problems, or to do your work for you. What are the errors you are getting? Have you searched anything about those errors?

Comment: Please also show the code that's generating the error - in other words, what are you doing in `bear_play`?

Comment: To solve this problem, you should think logical steps: 1. create a flag summer; 2. if summer is True, you need to check the temperature and return the value accordingly. 3. If summer is False, you should do another temperature 'if check' and return the result accordingly. It will be an if inside another if.

Answer (score 0):

Time for python one-liners:

```
do_bears_play = lambda t, is_summer: 60 <= t <= (100 if is_summer else 90)
```